# Acoustic absorption coefficient of Metals

Tags: quantum-mechanics, acoustics, metals, absorption

Which non toxic Metals have the lowest Acoustic absorption coefficient?

Comment: You need to add a lot more detail about the specific setup the metal is used and how it interacts with the sound field. If this is about materials for the walls of a container or room than the question is misguided. The absorption of those depends primarily of the construction details, not the material.

Comment: @Hilmar I am looking for the perfect metal for a stethoscope Bell, i figured therefore a metal with a low Acoustic absorption coefficient would Be good but i can't find a list or smth Like that

Comment: Any material that's rigid and non-porous will be behave the same acoustically. The exact geometry of the bell and the coupling to the tube and the earpieces will make much much more of a difference.

Comment: @Hilmar okay, thank you. Uhm have you a suggestione for the geometry?

Comment: Not without doing some research and math first. Maybe start with an exponential horn. These make good impedance transformers

Comment: @Hilmar an exponetnial Horn Is not really possibile for a stethoscope, maybe at the coupling part between chestpiece and tubing but It would end in the tubing and the binaurals are usually a Little less in their lumen Diameter so idk If It would make a Hughe difference. However today i thought of a acoustic fresno Lens that's Could focus the sound coming from the skin into the tubing.. do you think that would Be an realistic Option?